# Android Studio: Why does my New project contain 2 modules

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-library, android-studio

In a new Android Studio project, when I view Project Structure, there are 2 modules.  One is "ProjectName" and the other is "ProjectName-ProjectName".  Did I do something wrong when creating the project?

[image: Android Studio Project Structure]

Comment: What was you project structure in ADT ?

Comment: This is a brand new project in Android Studio.  Added a Screenshot

Comment: This is Gradle's default structure.  There is a top-level project (testing), and within it you will have sub-projects (testing, etc.).  Look in your settings.gradle - it should say the following: include ':testing'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When creating new projects, we always create a top level project with a single module in it.
Studio or IntelliJ will show both in the module list but the top one ("testing") doesn't output anyway.

We do this instead of a flat structure in the root project, so that it will allow you later to easily add new modules (like libraries) without having to convert the structure of your project.

what matters is the "testing-testing" module (we'll probably rename this "testing-main" at some point). the other module doesn't do anything. If you look at its build.gradle it's empty, while the other one declares an Android project.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much for the detailed description.

Comment: wait so this is actually by design? i've been fighting IntelliJ trying to track down the reference to this top level project and delete it yet it keeps showing up... i didnt expect that this is a 'feature'

Comment: @MrTristan it's tied to your Gradle project. You could convert your Gradle project to have a single root project and not sub-projects and then re-import it.

Comment: Interesting, my project is indeed a single root project with a 'submodules' folder which holds a bunch of git submodules that i have as 'modules' within IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar set of .iml files as yours, using an older version of Android Studio, but after upgrading to a later version it created yet another .iml, so then there was a top-level project.iml with a module containing module.iml and module-module.iml.

As far as I could tell, the module-module.iml file was useless, and the key information was in module.iml. However, even if I deleted all the iml files, Android Studio would recreate all of them, so I realized it was storing enough information in the [project]/.idea/modules.xml to recreate the iml files from scratch.

So I exited Android Studio, deleted the .idea folder and the .iml files, then relaunched Android Studio and imported the project using the build.gradle files. It recreated only project.iml and module.iml, and everyone is happy.

**SUMMARY:** 
As long as your gradle.build files are clean, then you can delete the .idea and .iml files, import the project using the gradle files, and get a nice clean project structure.

Comment: It's unbelievable that 7+ years after the initial report and confusions the problem still exists. Thank you for the "summary", this should be a short accepted answer :)